# Pie Charts in Chartkicks rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

Using chartkicks for showing charts in rails.It works fine but in pie_charts it show only percentage .I want that count of data also shown.

[image]

My query now is

```
<%= pie_chart users.all.group('users.gender').count.map { |k, v| [User.genders.key(k), v] }.to_h %>
```

Comment: just checked out, it does shows the number for each of them.

Comment: it only show when move cursor on it.I want all time

Comment: I am not sure about the way through Chartkicks but if you can store `Goal.group(:name).count` this value into a variable and then pass it to `pie_chart` and at the same time you can try printing the value next to it. I dont know if that will work, just a quick thought. :)

Comment: I update my question you can see my query. Which changes you say?

Comment: I am sorry, it wont work this way just tried on my system.

Comment: Its not implemented yet I guess, I can see an open issue here regarding the same: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/80